# Are the voices of the younger versions of the triplets dubbed by the older actors in This is Us?

Tags: film-techniques, acting, dubbing, this-is-us

*This is Us* jumps backwards and forwards through the lives of three siblings, their parents and family.

The teen versions of the triplets in particular sound a lot like the adult versions. Is there any dubbing or voice merging going on to achieve this or is it just a combination of good casting and imitation on the part of the young actors?

I’m aware that similar techniques have been used in other productions, such as *Bohemian Rhapsody*.